# Prove that $\Pi_{i \in I} \mathbf{A}_i \cong \Pi_{j \in J} (\Pi_{i \in I_j} \mathbf{A}_i)$ where $\{I_j \ | \ j \in J\}$ is a partition of I.

Tags: logic, model-theory, universal-algebra

My problem is following: prove that $\Pi_{i \in I} \mathbf{A}_i \cong \Pi_{j \in J} (\Pi_{i \in I_j} \mathbf{A}_i)$, where $\langle \mathbf{A}_i \ | \ i \in I \rangle$ is an indexed set of similar algebras and $\{I_j \ | \ j \in J\}$ is a partition of I.

It is so called *generalized associative law* for the product of algebras.

I was informed that the isomorphism is given by: $ a \mapsto \langle \langle a(i) \ | \ i \in I_j \rangle \ | \ j \in J\rangle$

How to prove that this map (say $h$) is a homomorphism, that is $$h(F^{\Pi_{i \in I} \mathbf{A}_i} (a_1, \dots, a_n))  = F^{\Pi_{j \in J} (\Pi_{i \in I_j} \mathbf{A}_i)} (h(a_1), \dots, h(a_n)),$$ where $F$ is a functional symbol from the signature.

My calculations are so massive and elaborative that I hardly believe they are correct and sincerely speaking I'm not quite sure I can see the idea behind them.

In the fist step I apply $h$ to the argument $F^{\Pi_{i \in I} \mathbf{A}_i} (a_1, \dots, a_n)$ and obtain from the definition of $h$: $$\langle \langle F^{\Pi_{i \in I} \mathbf{A}_i} (a_1, \dots, a_n)(i) \ | \ i \in I_j \rangle \ | \ j \in J \rangle$$ which by the definition of product is $$\langle \langle F^{\mathbf{A}_i} (a_1(i), \dots, a_n(i)) \ | \ i \in I_j \rangle \ | \ j \in J \rangle.$$ Because $i \in I_j$ and $I_j \subseteq I$ ($I_j$ is a block of our partition), $a(i) = \langle a(i) \ | \ i \in I_j \rangle (i)$ so what we've got equals  $$\langle \langle F^{\mathbf{A}_i} (\langle a_1(i) \ | \ i \in I \rangle (i), \dots, \langle a_n(i) \ | \ i \in I \rangle (i)) \ | \ i \in I_j \rangle \ | \ j \in J \rangle,$$ which in turn equals $$ \langle F^{\Pi_{ i \in I_J} \mathbf{A}_i} (\langle a_1(i) \ | \ i \in I \rangle, \dots, \langle a_n(i) \ | \ i \in I) \rangle) \ | \ j \in J \rangle.$$

From now my reasoning is vague. Is the presented argument correct? If it is, how to carry on? Could you give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: $\prod\gg\Pi$. In other words, the \prod symbol is orders of magnitude preferable to the capital Pi symbol as notation for a product.

Comment: I agree that dealing with products over arbitrary indexing sets is confusing. Why don't you try proving $\mathbf{A}_1\times\mathbf{A}_2\times\mathbf{A}_3\cong (\mathbf{A}_1\times\mathbf{A}_2)\times \mathbf{A}_3$?

Comment: @Eran I’m in a position to prove the specific case you’ve mentioned. However, the general case is the problem.

Comment: Your argument is correct. Before the last but one equality you have written $a(i) = \langle a(i) | i \in I_j \rangle(i)$, but in equality you change $I_j$ for $I$ (here is the misprint which keeps you from carrying on).